# Location of php.ini?

Tags: memory-management, php

I have to increase my memory limit, but there is no `php.ini` anywhere on my server.

When I query `php_info()`, it says it's in a folder called `web/conf`, but there is no such folder on my server. I looked in every folder.

Comment: Do you have root access to your server?

Comment: how did you install php, what's your os...?

Comment: Yes it's not in any root folders. I run Windows OS, but have a linux server. I don't remember if it's even installed or not. There is an empty folder PHP with nothing in it.

Comment: are you looking in every folder on the linux server? (try locate php.ini from the command prompt, or find / -name php.ini -print ) which will search the entire server for it.  If using apache you can also just create a .htaccess file that will override the memory limit as well.

Comment: i don't know where i would enter such a command as 'find'. i use FileZilla to connect. I did see an htaccess file. I suspect this has to with GoDaddy's epic fail of a hosting.

Comment: @user723220: Shared hosting like GoDaddy usually disallows editing of your `php.ini` file.

Comment: htaccess files contain nothing useful. php_info() says it's in web/conf, but that doesn't exist. I would download another php.ini but I don't know where the other is to overwrite. Screw it. I'm installing PHP over.

Comment: disallows editing of php??? I will call them tomorrow and tear off their heads

Comment: Shared hosting == You generally don't get to edit the php.ini file. You can try adding php_value memory_limit 16M to the .htaccess file in the root of your website (or increase the 16M to 32M, etc...)

Comment: yea it's time to upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the script:

```
<? phpinfo() ?>
```

And you'll see the path under the "Loaded Configuration File" value/row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a

```
find / -name "php.ini"
```

to locate your php.ini. If you have php installed, it will be there. If not, reinstall php.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to your php.ini file you can always set a configuration option at runtime with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can (re)install PHP by downloading [this](http://www.php.net/downloads.php) package and you can see a full tutorial over 
[here](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/how-to-install-php-5-on-linux-7-12-19-961/).   Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

C:\xampp\php\php.ini

I found this here:[PHP.ini location](http://www.linglom.com/images/Windows/Enable-cURL-on-XAMPP/1.png)